# Express to server static and handle apis is only giving me my static

Tags: node.js, express

My static folder has a react app and that works fine. What im trying to do is that any url that is api/{anything} it would go to that index route file and get handled there. Otherwise serve the static files. Currently it just always serves the static files.

My server.js file is as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

app.use('/api/*', routes);
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

And my routes/index file is

```
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/items/getAll', itemCtrl.getAllItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you remove the `/*` from your route everything should work as expected.